# Uncaught TypeError: check is not a function at HTMLInputElement.onclick

Tags: javascript

In this on clicking checkbox function defined in script is not called 
and error is coming what can i do for this?

```
<tr>
    <td>Enter Subject:</td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="subject" onclick="check();" class="subject" value="maths">
        Maths
        <input type="checkbox" name="subject" onclick="check();" class="subject" value="chemistry">
        Chemistry
    </td>
</tr>
<script>
    function check() { 
        check=true;
    }
</script>`
```

Comment: You're overriding the function `check`. First time it is called is OK, but second time you are calling a boolean as function.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i want to achieve if checkbox is checked or unchecked then this function would be called and check variable value will be vary from true or false.

Comment: @Aditya please look at my answer, otherwise please clarify what is you want to do...

Comment: @Anthony I tried your solution but it doesn't work

Comment: @Anthony i want to achieve if checkbox is checked or unchecked then this function would be called and check variable value will be vary from true or false

Comment: @Aditya I kind of understand what you want to do now. So basically you want to return the status of whether or not the box is checked? I'll adjust my answer. Let me know if that is what you're looking for, if not please explain a bit better

Answer (score 0):

[Checkboxes have a property called `checked`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp), which allows you to return and set whether or not a checkbox is checked.

```
<tr>
    <td>Enter Subject:</td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="subject" class="subject" value="maths">
        Maths
        <input type="checkbox" name="subject" class="subject" value="chemistry">
        Chemistry
    </td>
</tr>
<script>
    // this creates a collection of elements
    const subjectClass = document.getElementsByClassName("subject")

    // adds event listeners to those elements
    for (let i = 0; i < subjectClass.length; i++) {
        subjectClass[i].addEventListener('click', check)
    }

    function check(){
        console.log(`${this.value} is ${this.checked}`)
    }
</script>
```

Any time a checkbox is checked or unchecked, `check()` will log to the console the name of the subject and a Boolean value.

For example, "`maths is true`" (checked) or "`maths is false`" (unchecked).

The reason I used an event listener was so that `this` would end up representing whichever element or input that you interact with.

`this.checked` returns `true` if checked and `false` if unchecked.

**[Here is a codepen.](https://codepen.io/tOkyO1/pen/JvZpQv?editors=1111) (Make sure you open console in the bottom left hand corner.)**

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr>
    <td>Enter Subject:</td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="subject" onclick="check(this);" class="subject" value="maths">
        Maths
        <input type="checkbox" name="subject" onclick="check(this);" class="subject" value="chemistry">
        Chemistry
    </td>
</tr>
<script>
function check(e) { 
    e.checked=true;
}
</script>
```

Use a parameter to the function `check()` that accepts the input element as an argument (using `this`), and set the property `checked`, not `check`, to true. The `checked` indicates whether or not it is checked.